# How to select certain paths of a graph based on their length, using igraph in R

Tags: r, igraph

given a graph, for example:

```
require(igraph)
g <- graph.famous("Zachary")
```

such that some of its properties are:

```
diameter(g)
[1] 5
> farthest.nodes(g)
[1] 15 17  5
> average.path.length(g)
[1] 2.4082
> path.length.hist(g)
$res
[1]  78 265 137  73   8
$unconnected
[1] 0
```

As you can see there are 8 paths with length = 5, 73 with length = 4, and so on...

I would like to be able to isolate groups of nodes that are involved in a path of certain length. For example, I would like to know the nodes involve in the 73 paths of length 4, and their connected nodes respectively.

Let me clarify this with one easy example, the diameter of the graph. For this particular case one can do:

```
##names of the nodes involved in the diameter path of the graph
nodes.diameter<-get.diameter(g) 
edges <- as.data.frame(get.edgelist(g))
edges.diameter <- edges[which(edges$V1 %in% nodes.diameter),]
g.diameter <- graph.data.frame(edges.diameter, directed = FALSE)
##some aesthetics for the plot
V(g.diameter)$label.cex <- 1
plot(g.diameter,vertex.size=10)
```

[image]

This is a particular example because is easy to get the node names for the diameter. But, **is there a way to get the node names given a certain path length?** (naively, something like `get.path(g,length = X)`, and in a naive, ideal world this would return a list with the nodes involved in the paths of `length = X`. For example, for `length = 4`, the list would have length 73 elements each containing the nodes involved in each of the 73 paths of length 4)

many thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: Hi MrFlick. Actually, "find the paths with a particular path length, then extract the nodes from those paths" is exactly what I mean by "a way to get the node names given a certain path length". In other words, you have understood perfectly what I meant! :)  So, do you know how can I find the paths and then extract the node names?

Comment: My apologies MrFlick. Please, see the edited question with a full reproducible example that I hope further clarifies the goal of the question. I hope this makes it easier for you. Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `path.length.hist` function looks at all possible shortest paths. So these two commands are the same

```
# path.length.hist(g)$res
[1]  78 265 137  73   8

sp <- shortest.paths(g)
table(sp[upper.tri(sp)])
#   1   2   3   4   5 
#  78 265 137  73   8
```

which means the the information you are after can be extracted from `shortest.paths()`. Here's a function that will return the index of the vertices involved in the paths

```
get_paths_by_length <- function(g, len) {
    sp <- shortest.paths(g)
    sp[lower.tri(sp,TRUE)] <- NA
    wp <- which(sp==len, arr.ind=TRUE)
    mapply(function(a,b) get.shortest.paths(g, a, b)$vpath, wp[,1], wp[,2])
}
```

which returns

```
get_paths_by_length(g,5)
# [[1]]
# [1] 15 33  3  1  6 17
# [[2]]
# [1] 16 33  3  1  6 17
# [[3]]
# [1] 17  6  1  3 33 19
# [[4]]
# [1] 17  6  1  3 33 21
# [[5]]
# [1] 17  6  1  3 33 23
# [[6]]
# [1] 17  6  1  3 28 24
# [[7]]
# [1] 17  6  1  9 34 27
# [[8]]
# [1] 17  6  1  3 33 30
```

for the eight paths of length 5.

Comment: MrFlick, thank you very VERY much. This es exactly what I want...and again, my apologies for not having uploaded a fully reproducible example before. Thanks again.

Comment: I believe you'll need `get.all.shortest.paths`, otherwise you'll miss some vertices on non-unique shortest paths.

Comment: Good point @GaborCsardi. I didn't worry about non-unique paths. Wasn't sure how the OP wanted to handle that case.

Comment: Thanks Gabor, I noticed that. I was now working on it. By the way, I am, at the moment, reading your book with Kolaczyk :). Nice one.