# R: Creating the longest name chain in a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, subset, sequence

I have a dataframe of over 5,000 first names and last names. Here is the first 20 rows.

```
df <- data.frame(
        First.Name = c("Larry","Darren","Howard",
                       "Antonio","John","Alex","Tom","Jose","Robert","Michael",
                       "Will","Kareem","Jack","Howard","Sam","David",
                       "Carlo","Johnson","Andy","Rodger"),
         Last.Name = c("James","King","Singer",
                       "Howard","Michael","Peters","John","Reyes",
                       "Blake","Samuel","Woods","Patrick","Shun",
                       "Dieter","Johnson","Fant","Patrick","James",
                       "Berry","Black")
)
```

What I'm trying to do is create name chains and find the longest name chain possible. E.g Antonio Howard and Howard Singer connect creating the chain "Antonio Howard Singer".  Each name can be used once. I think I did a ton of overthinking but I came up with a code that works partially. It allows me to find the number of names in the longest chain for each name and shows me the indices of rows that have a matching first name to the last name of the given row. Here is the code so you can better understand:

```
#Store the indices of each person's name match in a list
matches <- list()

for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
  x <- c()
  for (j in 1:nrow(df)) {
    if (df$Last.Name[i] == df$First.Name[j]) {
      x <- c(x,j)
    } 
  }
  print(i)
  matches[[i]] <- x
}



#Function to get the indices of each person's matches


getmatches <- function(x){
  a <- c()
  if (length(x) < 1){
    break()
  } else{
    for(i in 1:length(x)){
      a <- c(a, matches[[x[i]]])
    }
  }
  if(length(a) >= 1){
    for (j in 1:length(a)){
      #Remove if a last name is the same as the person's own first name
      if (a[j] == x){
        a <- a[-j]
      } else {
        next()
      }
    }
  }  
  return(a)
}


#Get the length of longest name chain starting with each 
#person's name

df$longestchain <- 0

for (i in 1:nrow(df)){
  y <- getmatches(df[i])
  x <- 1
  while(length(y) > 0){
    x <- x + 1
    y <- getmatches(y)
  }
  df$longestchain[i] <- x
}
```

This gives me the name that starts the longest name chain and I can look at the matches from the matches list and come up with the longest name chain. However, this is not the most efficient way of doing things and does not work for more complicated tasks. For example: If every first/last name combination also counts as the opposite (Larry James can also be James Larry). How can I adjust this, or totally recreate it so the algorithm just gives me the longest name chain using each name once?

Comment: https://lists.nongnu.org/archive/html/igraph-help/2011-07/msg00046.html ?

Answer (score 2):

Convert to graph and subset the paths whose distance is equal to the diameter of the graph.

```
library(igraph)

g = graph.data.frame(df, directed = FALSE)
#plot(g)

d = diameter(g)

sp = shortest.paths(g)

# From https://stackoverflow.com/a/28054408/7128934
get_paths_by_length <- function(g, len) {
    sp <- shortest.paths(g)
    sp[lower.tri(sp,TRUE)] <- NA
    wp <- which(sp==len, arr.ind=TRUE)
    mapply(function(a,b) get.shortest.paths(g, a, b)$vpath, wp[,1], wp[,2])
}

get_paths_by_length(g, d)

#$Larry
#+ 4/33 vertices, named, from e20fe05:
#[1] Larry   James   Johnson Sam    

#$Tom
#+ 4/33 vertices, named, from e20fe05:
#[1] Tom     John    Michael Samuel
```

Comment: Thank you! Do you have any additional reading you can recommend so I can better understand how this works?

Comment: Did some reading and I believe my problem is trying to find the longest path instead of the shortest path

Answer (score 0):

I think this can be a simple `merge` (or join):

```r
out <- merge(df, df, by.x = "Last.Name", by.y = "First.Name", all = TRUE)
out <- out[ complete.cases(out), ]
out[,c(2, 1, 3)]
#    First.Name Last.Name Last.Name.y
# 12    Antonio    Howard      Dieter
# 13    Antonio    Howard      Singer
# 17        Tom      John     Michael
# 18        Sam   Johnson       James
# 23       John   Michael      Samuel
```

Okay, now let's automate this to find longer chains.

```r
outs <- list(df)
iter <- 50
while (iter > 0 && NROW(last <- tail(outs, 1)[[1]]) > 0) {
  this <- merge(last, df, by.x = tail(names(last),1), by.y = "First.Name")
  outs <- c(outs, list(this[, c(intersect(names(last), names(this)), setdiff(names(this), names(last)))]))
}

outs
# [[1]]
#    First.Name Last.Name
# 1       Larry     James
# 2      Darren      King
# 3      Howard    Singer
# 4     Antonio    Howard
# 5        John   Michael
# 6        Alex    Peters
# 7         Tom      John
# 8        Jose     Reyes
# 9      Robert     Blake
# 10    Michael    Samuel
# 11       Will     Woods
# 12     Kareem   Patrick
# 13       Jack      Shun
# 14     Howard    Dieter
# 15        Sam   Johnson
# 16      David      Fant
# 17      Carlo   Patrick
# 18    Johnson     James
# 19       Andy     Berry
# 20     Rodger     Black
# [[2]]
#   First.Name Last.Name Last.Name.y
# 1    Antonio    Howard      Dieter
# 2    Antonio    Howard      Singer
# 3        Tom      John     Michael
# 4        Sam   Johnson       James
# 5       John   Michael      Samuel
# [[3]]
#   First.Name Last.Name.y Last.Name.x Last.Name.y.y
# 1        Tom     Michael        John        Samuel
# [[4]]
# [1] First.Name    Last.Name.y   Last.Name.x   Last.Name.y.y Last.Name    
# <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

The names will continue to be obscure here, but (1) the `while` loop accepts the names as-is, (2) the names will not conflict (per `merge`'s logic), and (3) we can always sort them out later.

I added the `iter` counter/limiter in the event that there is enough commonality that a name could self-merge in a loop. I don't know that it *can* happen, but since I have not proven that it *cannot* happen, I guard against an infinite loop.

Comment: This works for name chains of 2 names but imagine there is another person called Singer Jones and another one called Jones Mack. How can I retrieve Antonio Howard Singer Jones Mack and confirm that it is the longest chain that can be created with the names in the dataframe? This does not achieve that

Comment: I see. I saw the request for a chain of two, did not yet imagine extending this much longer. I see your point.